# How enhanced ecommerce handles optional checkout steps?

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I am trying to implement enhanced ecommerce using Google Tag Manager and currently in the process of setting up dataLayer. In the checkout process on the website, the step for viewing cart is optional i.e user can either choose to 'view cart' or 'checkout' after adding product(s) to cart. My question is, should I include 'view cart' as step 1 in the checkout process? I want to, as it would provide me more visibility into % of user abandoning the process after viewing cart. Since it is an optional step, what do I need to do when users are skipping this step. Simply start the checkout process at step 2 or is there a better way to handle this. Please advise.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask such questions there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would track the cart as step 1 and the next step in the process as step 2. This will give you insight into drop-off between the cart and checkout in the Checkout Behavior report. Users skipping the cart will be easily discernable as a block on top of step 2 in the funnel, like so:

> [image: Google Analytics Checkout Behavior Report]

(But "Billing and Shipping" will be "Cart" and "Payment" whatever your first checkout step is.)

Another option is to track the skipped optional step when the next step occurs. So if 2 is skipped, track 2 and 3 on step 3.